# How to make a Cordova plugin output reactive in Meteor?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm using Cordova's [network information plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) in my meteor mobile app.

**global helpers**

```
Template.registerHelper("equals", function (a, b) {
    return (a == b);
});

Template.registerHelper ("networkType", function(){
    return navigator.connection.type;
});
```

**Template**

```
{{#if equals networkType 'none' OR equals networkType 'unknown'}}
    <div style="color:#f00;">WARNING: Looks like no Internet connection is active</div>
{{/if}}
```

It works but only when rendering template. If I disable wifi or 3g connection, nothing changes (I also tried to print network info directly in template. it's static).

provided that the network connection type **mustn't** imply user intervention, how do I make **networkInfo** global helper **reactive** ?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but the [docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information#network-related-events) seem clear:

Given your template code, I'm going to assume that you only care about connected/unconnected states (not the particular types of connections that may not all be supported by different devices).  Also, [the browser-quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information#browser-quirks) section in the docs suggests that Connedction.UNKNOWN is an online state, so I've only checking for Connection.NONE.

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE){
    Session.set('networkState', 'Not Connected');
  } else {
    Session.set('networkState', 'Connected');
  }
  document.addEventListener("offline", function(){
      Session.set('networkState', 'Not Connected');
    }, false);

  document.addEventListener("online", function(){
      Session.set('networkState', 'Connected');
    }, false);
});

Template.registerHelper ('networkOffline', function(){
  return Session.get('networkState') === 'Not Connected';
}

{{#if networkOffline}}
  <div style="color:#f00;">WARNING: Looks like no Internet connection is active</div>
{{/if}}
```

If you need to determine between the various online states, you can't use the callbacks, and will need to setup a polling solution.  Replace the 2 callbacks with:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
    Session.set('networkState', navigator.connection.type);
  }, 2000);
```